Imperativ in der indirekten Rede
Ich habe zu diesem Thema folgende Beispiele gefunden:

Er bat mich (freundlich), ich möge mich nicht so aufregen.
Er befahl uns (scharf), wir sollten aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.

Aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie diese zwei Sätze aussehen würden, wenn die Zahl anders wäre. Sind die folgenden Versionen richtig?

Er bat uns (freundlich), wir möchten (?) uns nicht so aufregen.
Er befahl mir (scharf), ich solle (?) aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.


Die üblichste Art, Imperativ in wörtlicher Rede wiederzugeben, ist mit "sollen".

Er befahl mir scharf, ich solle aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.

ist auf jeden Fall richtig.
Eine häufige Art, Menschen, um etwas zu bitten, ist "mögen/möchten" zu verwenden. Das kann man dann auch in der indirekten Rede benutzen, wie in deinem Beispiel

Er bat mich freundlich, ich möge mich nicht so aufregen.

Als du dann in den Plural wechseln wolltest, ist dir richtig aufgefallen, dass Konjunktiv I "mögen" und Indikativ gleich sind, und hast daher Konjunktiv II "möchten" verwenden wollen:

*Er bat uns freundlich, wir möchten uns nicht so aufregen.

Das Problem mit "mögen" ist allerdings, dass die Konjunktiv-II-Formen "möchten" so häufig verwendet werden, dass sie gar nicht wie ein Konjunktiv wirkt. So ist z. B. "Wenn du möchtest" kein irrealer Wunsch, sondern genauso realistisch wie "Wenn du willst". Will man es irreal, so würde man "Wenn du es mögen würdest" verwenden.
Daher solltest du, auch wenn es gleich klingt, hier beim Konjunktiv I bleiben, vor allem, da an dieser Stelle kein Indikativ stehen kann.

Er bat uns freundlich, wir mögen uns nicht so aufregen.

Mir ist mögen hier aber etwas suspekt, ich würde mit "bitten" Infinitiv, also

Er bat uns freundlich, uns nicht so aufzuregen.

verwenden. Das ist genauso flexibel wie indirekte Rede:

Er bat uns freundlich, uns nicht so aufzuregen, die Kinder schliefen / würden schlafen.


Vielen Dank für eine aufschlussreiche Erklärung!

Die Form möge ist eine Form des Verb mögen:

Erste Person, Singular, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, ich möge keinen Fisch.
Er bat mich, ich möge mich nicht so aufregen.


Dritte Person, Singular, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, Sebastian möge keinen Fisch.
Er bat Jürgen, er möge sich nicht so aufregen.



Du suchst die Plural-Form der ersten Person. Diese Form ist aber nicht möchten sondern mögen. (Das trifft auch auf die Plural-Form in der dritten Person zu.)

Erste Person, Plural, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, wir mögen keinen Fisch.
Er bat uns, wir mögen uns nicht so aufregen.


Dritte Person, Plural, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, die Leute mögen keinen Fisch.
Er bat die Leute, sie mögen sich nicht so aufregen.




Beim zweiten Satz ist dein Vorschlag für die Singular-Form korrekt. Aber die Plural-Form, von deren Korrektheit du auszugehen scheinst, ist streng genommen nicht ganz korrekt. Die Form sollten ist nämlich nicht Konjunktiv I, sondern Konjunktiv II. Allerdings darf man immer dann, wenn der Konjunktiv I identisch mit dem Indikativ ist, anstelle des Konjunktiv I den Konjunktiv II verwenden.

Erste Person, Singular, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, ich solle doch mehr Fisch essen.
Er befahl mir, ich solle aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.


Dritte Person, Singular, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, Sebastian solle doch mehr Fisch essen.
Er befahl mir, ich solle aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu


Erste Person, Plural, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, wir sollen doch mehr Fisch essen.
Sabine hat gesagt, wir sollten doch mehr Fisch essen.
Er befahl uns, wir sollen aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.
Er befahl uns, wir sollten aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.


Dritte Person, Plural, Konjunktiv I, Präsens, Aktiv:

Sabine hat gesagt, die Leute sollen doch mehr Fisch essen.
Sabine hat gesagt, die Leute sollten doch mehr Fisch essen.
Er befahl den Leuten, sie sollen aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.
Er befahl den Leuten, sie sollten aufhören, über das Wahlergebnis zu diskutieren.




Vielen Dank für die Erklärung und die Beispiele!
